# Visual proof for $[\triangle ABC] = rs$?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, geometric-construction, visualization

I'm teaching a high school geometry class and we just got to the part where we proved that the area of a triangle $[\triangle ABC]$ is equal to the inradius $r$ times the semiperimeter $s$.

A student pointed out to me that it's really the same thing as $[\triangle ABC] = \frac{1}{2}rp$ where $p$ is the perimeter. But this representation looks like the regular formula $\frac{1}{2}bh$.

So I was wondering if there's a way to take the original $\triangle ABC$ and construct a new triangle that will have a base of $p$ and a height of $r$ and show that the original and newly constructed triangle have the same area?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible. In fact, in $\Delta ABC$, extending $BC$ to $A'$ and then to $B'$ such that
$$ CA'=AC, A'B'=AB $$
one has
\begin{eqnarray}
S_{\Delta ABC}&=&S_{\Delta OBC}+S_{\Delta OAC}+S_{\Delta OBC}=\frac12ra+\frac12rb+\frac12rc\\
&=&S_{\Delta OBC}+S_{\Delta OCA'}+S_{\Delta OA'B'}=S_{\Delta OBB'}. 
\end{eqnarray}
[image]

Comment: Thanks! after reading this answer, it kind of seems obvious now. Especially since the second proposition of The Elements is to copy a length of a segment coming from a new point. So it seems like constructing $CA'$ and $A'B'$ would be pretty easy.

Or perhaps, now even easier: extend BC infinitely in each direction. Then Use a compass to draw circles centered at $B$ with radius $AB$ and centered at $C$ with radius $CA$. Then where the circles intersect the extended $BC$ that's where $A'$ and $B'$ can go.

Thanks for answering! But now I see how obvious it was the whole time!

Comment: Glad I can help you. I taught high school math many years ago.

Answer (score 6):

In case you're also interested in a rectangle, I made a diagram.

[image]

Rotate one in each pair of the congruent right triangles to obtain a rectangle.

[image]Indeed its length is $$ \color{blue}{(s-a)} + \color{red}{(s-b)} + \color{green}{(s-c)} = s$$

and clearly, $$ rs = \triangle$$

Comment: Nice! Another great one. I'll definitely be showing this to my students!